# Setting up and calling a proxy on my controller from Javascript via URL?

Tags: apex, javascript, jquery

So far, from what I have found, I made this method in my controller:

```
global static HTTPResponse Pdf_Export_Save(String contentType, String base64, String fileName){
    system.debug('Http Response Method');
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=' + fileName);
    req.setBody(base64);
    Http http = new Http();

    return http.send(req);
}
```

Then in Javascript, I set up the Pdf settings for a widget:

```
pdf: {
    fileName: 'Current-Schedule-View.pdf',
    proxyTarget: '_blank',
    forceProxy: true,
    proxyURL: //Need to call my controller method here
}
```

What I am needing to happen is set a proxyURL and force the proxy each time someone downloads the pdf of the current widget view. Then in that proxy, change the header so that it insteads opens the PDF in a new window/tab instead of downloading.

This is in an attempt to overcome Lightning issues with downloading a PDF from a visualforce page in Lightning Experience, which gets placed in an iframe and Lightning doesn't allow downloads.

Changing the file header in the proxy function is all I have found on how to get around this.

**My problem:** I do not know how to exactly call my proxy method from the proxyURL field. Can I trigger my controller method via URL? Like: '/stuff/stuff/Pdf_Export_Save'. If not, how might one call out to a proxy in my controller?

I appreciate any guidance on this as I am new to doing this kind of callout in Apex. But it is all I found to do to change from downloading the pdf to opening it in a new window/tab. However, I cannot find information on doing this kind of thing in Apex to translate the examples I found into Apex.

Comment: try using javascript remoting to call method.

Comment: The issue with that is, the proxy the widget will use will take in three parameters, and doing the remoting method, I need to pass in the parameters to get them to send. But I don't actually have the parameters... The widget just sends them to the proxy method that is specified in proxyURL.